# jwt.php not visible in config folder of laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan

I have successfully configured and make everything work perfectly. But i have an issue, i want to change the time to live but in my project "jwt.php" does not appear in the config folder.

If anyone knows the solution kindly guide me; help will be appreciated.
Many Thanks!

Comment: `jwt.php` is not a standard laravel file. What did you successfully configure? What does change the time live mean?

Comment: @developernator I have been using jwt for the rest api authentication, there i need that file for some changes.

Comment: what is the package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because you haven't published vendor files.

You should run:

```
php artisan config:publish tymon/jwt-auth
```

assuming you use https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth package to publish configuration file so you will have `jwt.php` created and then you can update config according to your needs

Comment: thanks for the help. Now I have got the jwt.php file.

Answer (score 0):

To publish vendor files, for Laravel 5.5, run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=config
```